# Is $\sum n^2 a_n \le C \sum a_n$ for some $C \gt 0$ if $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Specifically,

Suppose I have a collection of sequences $(a_n^{(i)})_{n=0}^\infty$ for $i \in I$ such that for all $i \in I$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 |a_n^{(i)}| \lt \infty.$$

Does there exist a $C \gt 0$, not dependent on $i$, such that for all $i\in I$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2|a_n^{(i)}| \le C\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n^{(i)}| ?$$

It is pretty easy to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n^{(i)}|$ converges for every $i\in I$, but the challenge I am having is finding a constant that can "get rid of" the $n^2$ in the sum.

I am pretty sure the answer to this question is "yes," but I am having trouble proving it. I would be surprised, but grateful to anyone that could provide a counterexample.

Comment: Consider sequences with a single nonzero term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No."

Daniel Fischer left a comment to consider sequences with a single non-zero term.

Consider the collection of sequences $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $e_k$ is the sequence of $0$s with a $1$ in the $k^{th}$ place. Then we have that,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2e_k = k^2,$$

for all $k$. Hence, there is no C>0 such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2e_k = k^2 \le C = C\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e_k.$$